# Open Google Maps or new browser from android webview using only Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, webview

I have a problem where I need to open Google Maps app on Android from a click within webview.  All of my searches come up with modifying the webview settings in the android code.  I am not able to do this.  I only have access to the webpage that is open in the webview.  I can not modify the java in android, I have to use Javascript on the page.

I have tried using:

window.location.href = http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr= but I only get maps open on a webpage not the app.

window.open(same link as above) same problem only opens inside webview.

href="intent://#Intent;package=com.google.android.apps.maps;action=http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=...;end;" 
Did not get anything from this.  Read somewhere that I have to change something in the android manifest to use this, but I do not have access to that.

Any Ideas?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the geo links instead of the maps.google.com:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Maps

I tested it with

```
<a href="geo:37.786971,-122.399677;u=35">click</a>
```

and it works.

=-=-=- edit -=-=-=

After some more digging, it turns out that the default behavior of WebView on 5.0 or after is not to support url scheme, unless you override the function.

In your case, I think the best you can do it to load the web version for 5.0 or later users, and open the maps app for other users. The follow code should do that.

```
    String htmlString = "<p id=\"demo\" onclick=\"myFunction()\">Click me to open map.</p>\n" +
            "<script>\n" +
            "function myFunction() {\n" +
            "    document.getElementById(\"demo\").innerHTML = \"<iframe style=\\\"display:none\\\" src=\\\"geo:37.786971,-122.399677;u=35\\\"></iframe>\";\n" +
            "    window.open(\"http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=37.786971,-122.399677\");\n"+
            "}</script>\n";
```

Comment: kaho thank you for your answer.  Unfortunately it did not work for me.  If I make a link like you did on the page it works, but I need it in an if else statement.  I get :  "the website at geo:0,0?q=... might be temporarily down or it may have moved..." 
 It is inside of a function that checks what mobile device you are accessing from. 
 if{...} 
else{ window.location.href="geo:0,0?q="+address;}

Comment: huh.. yea, I think the `window.open()` works on 4.4 or below; I tried and it fail on 5.1.1, as well as M.